# get all database name with stsadm

Tags: powershell, stsadm

I want to know to get all database name with an stsadm commend like Get-SPDatabase in power shell 
I found this cmd:`stsadm -o databaserepair -url http://xyz/sites/sc -databasename DBname`

but it need  a specified database and url .
there is any idea .
beast regards .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stsadm –o enumcontentdbs` only returns content database. To find other DBs:

> Content DBs: These are actually listed quite nicely in central admin.
>   At least they gave us that: APP MANAGEMENT >> CONTENT DATABASES >>
>   select each WEB APP you want to see a list of content DBs for. Config
>   DBs: This one was tricky and took me a while. Turns out this info is
>   in the registry. Sigh. REGEDIT >> HKLMSoftwareMicrosoftShared ToolsWeb
>   Server Extensions12.0SecureConfigDb SSP Config and Search DB: This one
>   was obvious in hindsight: Central Admin >> SHARED SERVICES
>   ADMINISTRATION >> click the EDIT PROPERTIES drop down on the SSP you
>   want to look at.

http://mnteractive.com/archive/how-to-list-all-sharepoint-databases/

Comment: stsadm -o Enumzoneurls // get urls
stsadm -o enumcontentdbs -url http://xyz  //get contentdbs for url .thanks Nadeem